# regex expression shell help finding the meaning

Tags: bash, shell, git

I am starting with bash and I had this expression line. I am lost figuring what it is means.

what does this line in shell regex expression mean?

```
find . -name '*.sh' | sed 's#.*/##' | sed 's#\.sh##'
```

Comment: If your system has the GNU Coreutils implementation of `basename`, you could consider using `find . -name '*.sh' -exec basename {} .sh \;` instead

Comment: or at least use a single sed e.g. `sed -e 's#.*/##'  -e 's#\.sh##'`

Comment: Following up @steeldriver's comment -- also: `find . -name '*.sh' | xargs basename -s '.sh'` -- should work on GNU and BSD basename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` statement searches the current directory and its sub-directories for all files ending in `.sh` and prints them one file per line.

The `s` operator of `sed` substitutes matched substrings with something else.
The syntax is `s<delimiter>regex<delimiter>replacement<delimiter>`.
Usually `/` is used as the *delimiter* but here `#` is used.

The *replacement* in both `sed` statements is the empty string.

Therefore the first statement cuts off everything before the last `/` in the filename (ie. the sub-directory).
The second statement cuts off the `.sh` suffix of the file name.

A file `a/subdir/hierarchy/my_script.sh` would be printed as `my_script`.